# How to connect UIViewController to UIView using storyboard segue, without any code?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboard

I am searching about some audio tutorial over internet and I eventually found a demo/example from apple. In this example I am wondering how they connect UIViewController to a UIView using storyboard segues.

[Download project from here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVAEMixerSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015134)

> Below is storyboard connections

[image]

> When we run app below is it's output

[image]

Can any one explain how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using *container views* to include child controllers defined somewhere else.

Its actually still a connection between 2 controllers. There is no independent view.

> To create a parent-child container relationship at design time, add a container view object to your storyboard scene, as shown in Figure 5-3. A container view object is a placeholder object that represents the contents of a child view controller. Use that view to size and position the child’s root view in relation to the other views in the container...

See [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) in the Apple docs, chapter Configuring a Container in Interface Builder.

Comment: I want to know about segue connections, as you can see UIView is not showing as default UIView. They made some changes so the uiview can connect to a view controller using connection.

Comment: @Sulthan, Please give reference or example for this.

Comment: @RajJoshi Added, I have originally posted the answer from my phone so I could not add the link.

Answer (score 1):

> > Here container view is using. Container view controllers are a way to combine the content from multiple view controllers into a single user interface. Container view controllers are most often used to facilitate navigation and to create new user interface types based on existing content. please view this [link for detail](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/container-view-controllers/)